# How to pass variables from .env or docker-compose.yaml file to nginx server file

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file and a `.env` file. If I declare a variable in the env file, I can access it in docker-compose. So, this is good.

But, I would like to change nginx's `default.conf` properties, namely the `server_name = xxx` to be generated from the value I provide in the env.

So, my env looks like this (only sharing a portion)

```
#.env
NGINX_SERVER_NAME=dev.example
```

In docker-compose I mention this variable here:

```
nginx:
  container_name: ${APP_NAME}-server
  environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}
```

And in `default.conf` I simple call the variable like this:

```
server_name ${SERVER_NAME};
```

I am expecting the `default.conf` to contain `server_name dev.example` but it contains the token i.e. `${SERVER_NAME}`

How can I achieve what I am looking for?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems ok to me. try to use quote around your env variable in compose file.

```
nginx:
  container_name: ${APP_NAME}-server
  environment:
    - SERVER_NAME="${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}"
```

or try to write your env variable like this.

```
nginx:
  container_name: ${APP_NAME}-server
  environment:
    SERVER_NAME: "${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}"
```